# Get third child on firebase database javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read third child from my firebase database: `Tahmin`.

```
|belesmaclar
---|maç1
   ---|Tahmin: "storeddata";
```

I did try the following methods below, but none of them worked.

```
var f1 = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('/belesmaclar/maç1/Tahmin');

var f1 = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("/belesmaclar/maç1/Tahmin");

var f1 = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("belesmaclar").child("maç1").child("Tahmin");
```

Thanks for any help.

```
var f1 = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("belesmaclar").child("maç1").child("Tahmin");

f1.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {
    head1.innerText = datasnapshot.val();
})
```

Comment: Have a look at the JS doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 0):

```
var f1 = firebase.database().ref('/belesmaclar/maç1/Tahmin');
f1.once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

The code above should work if you only want to read it once.
If you want to listen for changes you should use: 'on'

```
var f1 = firebase.database().ref('/belesmaclar/maç1/Tahmin');
f1.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: not work aganin.I can get one data with using this. var dar = firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("somedata");
dar.on('value' ,function(datasnapshot) {
 kok.innerText = datasnapshot.val();
 
})..But third not working.

Comment: I found the issue.The "ç" is nvalid character.

Answer (score 0):

Your key likely contains an incorrectly encoded character. The character "ç" itself is okay, but must be encoded in UTF8.

I would escape the "ç" character as `\xC3\xA7` rather than use it literally.

To streamline this process, you can also use the [`utf8`](https://npmjs.org/package/utf8) module.

### Relevant Documentation

From [Firebase Documentation > Web > Structure Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree)

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the values themselves, either.